# error: Undefined class 'LocaleListResolutionCallback'. (undefined_class at PROJECT_NAME] lib/generated/i18n.dart:36)

Tags: dart, flutter

My app was working fine until I recently updated my IntelliJ IDEA with new versions. 
My app started showing me an error. It is in file i18n.dart.

```
error: Undefined class 'LocaleListResolutionCallback'. (undefined_class at [PROJECTNAME] lib/generated/i18n.dart:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

After an update of intellij just run a flutter upgrade and the LocaleListResolutionCallback class will be resolved once more